# Why does my transform animation override my original transform?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I have three elements, Each of them with its own transform, and I want to animate their translate transform not affecting scale:

```css
.one{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
}
.two{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
}
.three{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce{
    from{
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 100px, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="one">test1</div>
<div class="two">test2</div>
<div class="three">test3</div>
```

But this transform overrides scale.
I could use different keyframes for each element. Or wrap each element and style its parent with scale transform and use one only keyframes to animate it. But this all is kind of tricky. Is there a better solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/422t2/

Answer (score 2):

You’re thinking about the transform property wrong. Each element has one transform property and you reset it with your per-element animations. You need to write an animation like this:

```css
.one{
    transform: scale(0.5);
    animation: bounce 1s ease 1s infinite alternate;
}

.two{
    transform: scale(0.5)
}

@keyframes bounce{
    from{
        transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    to{
        transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(100px, 100px, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="one">test1</div>
<div class="two">test2</div>
<div class="three">test3</div>
```

This preserves the scale component of your transform while allowing the browser to animate the translation. And in your case, you’d write a new animation for each class, and could drop the original scale declaration in favour of `animation-fill: both`

The other answers here add the animation to a wrapper `div`, which is a good solution, and if you mess with the `transform-origin` properties of all your elements and wrapper you should get a lot of flexibility. With a wrapper it’s easier to handle changing compound transformations, even a wrapper round each element can work out elegantly in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are overriding the original `transform` with the one in your animation.

You can wrap those three divs with another div and give animation to the wrap div

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/422t2/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="two"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1000ms infinite alternate;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't animate each element, it animates the wrapper as a whole

Answer (score 1):

try to add animation to each element and animation to the container:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/422t2/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="two"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce{
    from{
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 100px, 0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale1{
    from{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scale2{
    from{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scale3{
    from{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
    }
}
```